# Laravel Virgin: Get all configuration via `artisan tinker`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sometimes during testing I need to be able to find out how my laravel application is configured using `artisan tinker` command.

The problem is that I do not know what to type in order to do that. In many cases that would be usefull to me because I would be able to have a quick look on how the database is configured on different enviromental settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requested tinker `command` (actually is direct php interpeter with laravel loaded) is the following:

```
config()->all();
```

With that you can have a look on how enviromental variables are resolved and what is loaded into your case.